# How can I show array stored inside of array using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a table that shows the user data. See the code below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td><img src="{{user.picture}}" class="avatar"></td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>%</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href=""><button>Download</button></a></td>
</tr>
```

I have an array stored inside of my 'users' array, called 'workdata'. inside the 'workdata' array are a couple items I want to show on the page. When I try this `{{ user.workdata.hours_present }}` It does not show anything. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: because workdata is an array, and does not have a property hours_present

Answer (score 0):

If workdata is another array inside the users you need to use another ngFor within

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users"">
       <tr *ngFor="let workdataobj of user.workdata">
         <td>{{workdataobj.hours_present}}</td>
       </tr>
   <ng-container>
```

or you can access particular element using index,

```
<td><img src="{{user.workdata[0].hours_present}}" class="avatar"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to iterate of your users array, than you can iterate through your workdata array of each user.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users"">
    <tr *ngFor="let workData of user.workdata">
        <td>{{workData.hours_present}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```